# How to avoid `%` symbol injection using LIKE fuzzy query

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using like for fuzzy query, here is my code:

```rs
            let mut q = users::table.into_boxed();

            if let Some(email) = data.user.email {
                if !email.is_empty() {
                    q = q.filter(users::email.like(format!("%{}", email)));
                    dbg_sql!(q);
                }
            }
```

If I set `email=gmail%` while querying, it generates sql like this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` LIKE ?) -- binds: [\"%gmail%\"]
```

A `%` symbol is spliced at the end of sql, and unexpected results are obtained after execution. How to avoid this? Need to escape the email query field, or use other sql queries, how to avoid this in diesel What happens?

Comment: @chepner The code above _is_ doing a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

You want to escape the corresponding query string by using the corresponding [`.escape()`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/expression_methods/trait.EscapeExpressionMethods.html#method.escape) method.

Comment: How do I apply `escape()` to my code

Comment: There are a examples in the linked documentation.